# How do you implement a page template automatically being applied to a page?

Tags: pages, page-template

### Question

What can i do in a child theme to create a page template that will be selected by a new page by default. I wrote the page "default with sidebar" but **how do i actually implement it and get it working?**

### Background

I have a project that I am maintaining that uses [Understrap](https://understrap.com/). I created a template that has a left sidebar, but I need another page that displays a similar layout by default. Since it is not exact, I plan on using both "left sidebar page" and "default layout with sidebar".

I don't know where "default template" is, Ideally I could edit that.

[image]

### Previous research

There is a similar question(Is there a way to change the default page template selection?)[[Is there a way to change the default page template selection?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196289/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-page-template-selection]) but it was poorly phrased, they just asked **if** this was possible, which resulted in incomplete answers which did not discuss actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve your desired result is to create a template file in your child theme and name it page.php.
WordPress has a template hierarchy for template selection based on the queried object. See [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).