# Force a specific template as default

Tags: posts, templates, page-attributes

[ EDIT: I'm using Chaplin theme as the parent theme ]

I'm working on a child theme and I need to set a specific template as default for all posts (there's no custom post types, just regular posts).

Just to be clear: I need that every time a user adds a new post, "My custom template" is picked instead of the "Default template".

I asked the developer of the original theme for a suggestion and he pointed me to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/231503/58272). Then I edited the code to adapt it to my case (as I'm working on posts, not pages).

However, this code doesn't work for me, the Default template is still default.
This is the code I'm using:

```php
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_default_page_template', 1);
function my_default_page_template() {

    global $post;
    if ( 'post' == $post->post_type 
        && 0 != count( get_page_templates( $post ) ) 
        && get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) != $post->ID // Not the page for listing posts
        && '' == $post->page_template // Only when page_template is not set
    ) {
        $post->page_template = "my-custom-template.php";
    }

}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I'm no expert in coding and need someone to point me to the right direction (and possibly explaining me what I'm doing wrong so that I can learn something).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you still need the original template? Why not just replace the default template with your template in the child theme?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `yourtemplate.php` as the default, why don't you change the default template, and put the original default in `yourtemplate.php`? AKA swap them?

Otherwise you'll have to go back through all your posts and change them, and, mess around with complicated filters that might not work 100%

Comment: Thanks Tom, but this is not a solution in this case because of the way the parent theme was created. I didn't create the parent theme, so I have to stick with the original. If I could choose I'd certainly go this route (that's actually what I usually do).

Comment: You don't need to modify the parent theme to do this, but, you should explain in your question that you have unusual circumstances, including which theme you're using. I cannot imagine a scenario that would stop this from working, but, there is possibility that this problem can only be solved via the theme vendors support, or undoing what that theme is doing. Without knowing it's difficult to answer

Comment: I wrote that I'm working on a child theme and I'm not trying to modify the parent.  However, I'll edit the question to add the name of the parent theme (it's Chaplin by the way). Sorry if my comment wasn't clear, English is not my native language.